How to specify a specific package version in Ansible for apt_rpm module
Target host for Ansible is AltLinux server v10.2.
Now I do not know how to specify a specific package version for installation via apt_rpm module.
In official doc https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/apt_rpm_module.html there are no such examples.
Maybe there is a workaround for specifying specific package versions.
my playbook example:
  ---
  
  - hosts: all
    become: true
  
  tasks:
  
  - name: Install my package
    package:
    name: python3-module-yaml=6.0.1
    state: present
    update_cache: true

when I run via
ansible-playbook playbook.yml

I got error:
TASK [Install my package] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [test]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: '''apt-get -y install python3-module-yaml=6.0.1'' failed: '

In verbose mode:
docker-desktop:/ansible/host_group/altlinux_kubernetes# ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini -vvvv
ansible-playbook [core 2.15.5]
  config file = /ansible/host_group/altlinux_kubernetes/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /ansible/host_group/altlinux_kubernetes/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.11.6 (main, Oct  4 2023, 06:22:18) [GCC 12.2.1 20220924] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
Using /ansible/host_group/altlinux_kubernetes/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
Loading collection ansible.builtin from 
Parsed /ansible/host_group/altlinux_kubernetes/inventory.ini inventory source with ini plugin
redirecting (type: callback) ansible.builtin.yaml to community.general.yaml
Loading collection community.general from /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ansible_collections/community/general
redirecting (type: callback) ansible.builtin.yaml to community.general.yaml
Loading callback plugin community.general.yaml of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/callback/yaml.py
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.

PLAYBOOK: playbook.yml ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Positional arguments: playbook.yml
verbosity: 4
remote_user: sysop
connection: smart
timeout: 10
become_method: sudo
tags: ('all',)
inventory: ('/ansible/host_group/altlinux_kubernetes/inventory.ini',)
vault_password_files: ('/ansible/host_group/altlinux_kubernetes/vault',)
forks: 5
1 plays in playbook.yml

PLAY [all] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Trying secret FileVaultSecret(filename='/ansible/host_group/altlinux_kubernetes/vault') for vault_id=default

TASK [Install my package] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /ansible/host_group/altlinux_kubernetes/playbook.yml:6
redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.apt_rpm to community.general.apt_rpm
redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.apt_rpm to community.general.apt_rpm
Running apt_rpm
redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.apt_rpm to community.general.apt_rpm
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/apt_rpm.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<192.168.0.107> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: budnov
<192.168.0.107> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=1800s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="budnov"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/f8a796ea78"' 192.168.0.107 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=lawkbdlayeizmthnlwvbciscebcyfgnw] password:" -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-lawkbdlayeizmthnlwvbciscebcyfgnw ; /usr/bin/python3.9'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
<192.168.0.107> (1, b'\n{"failed": true, "msg": "\'apt-get -y install python3-module-yaml=6.0.1\' failed: ", "invocation": {"module_args": {"name": "python3-module-yaml=6.0.1", "state": "present", "update_cache": true, "package": ["python3-module-yaml=6.0.1"], "clean": false, "dist_upgrade": false, "update_kernel": false}}}\n', b"OpenSSH_9.3p2, OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.0.107 is address\r\ndebug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts'\r\ndebug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts2'\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 32\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 1\r\n")
<192.168.0.107> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_9.3p2, OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.0.107 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 32
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 1
fatal: [test]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  invocation:
    module_args:
      clean: false
      dist_upgrade: false
      name: python3-module-yaml=6.0.1
      package:
      - python3-module-yaml=6.0.1
      state: present
      update_cache: true
      update_kernel: false
  msg: '''apt-get -y install python3-module-yaml=6.0.1'' failed: '

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
test                       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Moreover, I can install a package of a specific version on the target host via apt-get:
[root@host-107 budnov]# apt-get install python3-module-yaml=6.0.1
Чтение списков пакетов... Завершено
Построение дерева зависимостей... Завершено
Selected version python3-module-yaml#6.0.1-alt1.1:p10+340092.554.16.1@1709018089 for python3-module-yaml=6.0.1
Следующие дополнительные пакеты будут установлены:
  libyaml2 python3-module-yaml
Следующие НОВЫЕ пакеты будут установлены:
  libyaml2 python3-module-yaml
0 будет обновлено, 2 новых установлено, 0 пакетов будет удалено и 31 не будет обновлено.
Необходимо получить 217kB архивов.
После распаковки потребуется дополнительно 906kB дискового пространства.
Продолжить? [Y/n] y
Получено: 1 http://ftp.altlinux.org p10/branch/x86_64/classic libyaml2 0.2.5-alt1:sisyphus+278391.100.1.1@1626094928 [49,9kB]
Получено: 2 http://ftp.altlinux.org p10/branch/x86_64/classic python3-module-yaml 6.0.1-alt1.1:p10+340092.554.16.1@1709018089 [167kB]
Получено 217kB за 0s (610kB/s).
Совершаем изменения...
Подготовка...                                                                             #################################################################################################### [100%]
Обновление / установка...
1: libyaml2-0.2.5-alt1                                                                    #################################################################################################### [ 50%]
2: python3-module-yaml-6.0.1-alt1.1                                                       #################################################################################################### [100%]
Завершено.


I assume you need to change the package name to python3-module-6.0.1 or python3-module-6.0.1-11 or so, since the equal sign (=) within the package name is clearly a syntax error.

@U880D, I tried different ways, but no luck. I think this module does not have this option. I opened issue on GitHub: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/8217

@НикитаБуднов it would probably make sense to either use the generic package module, or gather facts on the target system to select from yum and apt modules.

@Alexander Pletnev "package" manager module within itself selects the required internal module (yum, apt, apt_rpm...) to install packages. I have no luck even if I specify a fixed version for apt_rpm module via "=" or "-" or something else.

Instead of python3-module-yaml=6.0.1 I would try to use python3-module-yaml-6.0.1-alt1.1. This package is in:
https://packages.altlinux.org/en/p10/srpms/python3-module-yaml/rpms/3022462791212035973
This syntax with an equal sign in a package name looks strange to me and probably doesn't work with any package/yum/apt module in Ansible.
